# “Their Own Pages” or “Their Own Page”

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number

> Your images will have their own **pages/page**.

I want to talk about several images. Each image has one page.

Should I use **pages** or **page**?

Why?

Comment: Your images will have their own pages. Each of your images will have its own page.

Comment: I would say *pages*, but I would rewrite the sentence to eliminate the ambiguity: Each image will have its own page, or, each of your images will have its own page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Your images will each have its own page.

Using *each* here allows us to switch from talking about all the images in plural, to talking about one such image singularly, and hence we then have to talk about its page in the singular.

This allows you to be clear, avoiding the possible misinterpretation of each image perhaps having more than one page.

Conversely, someone else describing a different system where there could be more than one page per image, could do the opposite:

> Your images will each have its own pages.

This would serve the opposite case, where your intended meaning would of course be the possible misinterpretation.